# Submit all options from multi select list box with jquery.form.js plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

in my code, inside form, I have multi select list box:

```
<SELECT style="width: 250px;" id="data" multiple="multiple" name="data">
   <OPTION value="111" selected="selected">111</OPTION>
   <OPTION value="222">222</OPTION>
   <OPTION value="333">333</OPTION>
</SELECT>
```

[image]

For submitting the form I'm using [jquery.form.js](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var options = {
            beforeSubmit: showRequest, 
            success: showResponse  
        };

        $('#myForm').ajaxForm(options);
    });
```

The plugin submits only the values witch are selected: **111**. How to force it to serialize and submit all values, not only selected ones: **111**, **222** and **333** ?

Btw: The event showRequest looks following:

```
showRequest: function (formData, jqForm, options) {
            //.. 
            return true;
        },
```

I thaught I can modify formData inside this function, and pass this overloaded object for submitting. But there is no such option, is there ? Nothing changes also, when I iterate here through all select options and force all to have selected attribute.

Any ideas ? I'd like to use this plugin, I don't want to submit form by my custom code.

Regards

**Update:** @JK, @Luke, just for short explanation, I'd like to submit all options, despite selection, for example when I have following situation:
[image]

So I don't have list of strictly defined options, where I can just select or deselect some of them. In my case, I can create new options and I need the functionality I described.

Comment: how do you know then what was selected?

Comment: If its not selected why does it need to be posted back?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems you already have the data (in `formData`), so try to add a field there with all the values —how you serialize it is entirely your decision.

If this doesn't work, try adding hidden fields to store the values. You can either create one and enconde the values, or create many (with the same name), one for each value.

Comment: Hey, actually doing this in beforeSubmit event is too late. The plugin seems to have its own copy of formData which is already deserialized and is going to be submitted. In beforeSubmit event you can actually only preview what has been done, and have no possibility to change the submit data. Modifing formData has no sense in this case.